# Non-inverting op amps with sensors

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, inverter, pressure

I would like to know if there's a negative implication of using non-inverting op amps with sensors, for example a pressure sensor? Would it be a better option to use an inverter, and if it is, why?

Comment: The only downside **in general** for using non-inverting op-amp topologies is that they can only give Gain Factor > 1. However, if you realise you can use resistor dividers and unity-gain buffer topolgy to get Gain Factor < 1, then you can see that you never actually need to use inverting op-amps. You can even making [non-inverting summing amplifiers](https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-transfer-function-of-the-summing-amplifier-with-n-input-signals).

Answer (score 1):

Most sensors give an output which is a positive voltage or current. Most controllers using an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter) are restricted to positive voltages - typically 0 to 5 V. As a result the sensor signal can usually be interfaced directly (if the signal levels match), with a resistor divider (if the signal level is too high) or with an amplifier (if the signal voltage is too low).

Inverting a signal usually increases circuit complexity as additional components and dual-rail power-supplies are required. When a microprocessor is involved the signal can be rescaled digitally avoiding the need for external processing.

Comment: And the input impedance for an inverting amplifier is usually (always?) **much** lower than that of an non-inverting amplifier. Meaning that sensors with high output impedance should/can only use non-inverting amplifiers in order to get any sensible output that is not *insanely* distorted. - Though *some sensors* only works in inverting amplification mode.. - Oh well.